# convert oracle NUMBER to Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column in oracle where  the column has a
   datatype of `NUMBER(10,0)`.

In this column some one has stored a `timestamp`
   data.(Eg.3613470611,3613470666 etc..). I need to make a query which 
   to show the time difference between this `timestamp` and the
   `current_timestamp`.

`select (cast(current_TIMESTAMP as date)- date '1900-01-01')*24*60*60 - columen1 from mytable;`

(column1  is type of `NUMBER(10,0)`)
This query works fine.

The problem is, I am not able to convert the result to a date so that I can see the month, the date, the hour,

- The result I got is like this : `74873174`, `74873713` (I guess this
  not a timestamp, but a number)
- I like to convert like this format: `December 12, 2016 11:05:10`

So, please help !!

Comment: The difference between current time and `timestamp` is either an **INTERVAL** or a number. How you do like convert an interval or a number into a date? Assume the difference is 20 hours - which date do you like to be shown - `January 1, 0000 22:00:00`?

Comment: How does the data in `column1` in your table represent a timestamp? What is the unit (seconds? one one-thousandth of a second, aka millisecond? microsecond?) and when is it measured from? `1970-01-01`? `1900-01-01`? And, don't forget to answer Wernfried's question!

Comment: As @mathguy said, you can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586657/difference-between-two-year-month-and-day-values-in-oracle/35587150#35587150

Answer (score 0):

your number might be linux format numbers. simple answer for conversion is :

```
Select  to_date('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(yourNumber,'SECOND') from dual
```

Comment: I test your numbers and get (5/16/1972 2:06:14 PM) for (74873174) -> is it right?

Comment: I have no idea if 74873174=5/16/1972 2:06:14 PM. But how do you test it? Can you give me more info?

Comment: I just run above sql with your number :  Select  to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(74873174,'SECOND') from dual

Comment: `1900-01-01 00:00:00` + 3613470611 seconds is `2014-07-04 13:50:11`, so epoch of `1900-01-01 00:00:00` seems to be correct. `1970-01-01` would result into year 2084 - I doubt that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need Epoch Converter, something like that

```
SELECT to_date('01-JAN-1970','dd-mon-yyyy')+(1526357743/60/60/24) from dual
```

Replace 1526357743 with epoch.

More details see the link https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score -2):

Difference of dates is seconds, yeah it's number. Date is a number in Oracle. The integer part of the fraction is days, anything else is hours and seconds.
Here you have difference between dates in seconds

```
select (sysdate - date '1900-01-01')*24*60*60 from dual;
```

Here is current date + time difference in date format.

```
select sysdate+(cast (systimestamp as date) - date '1900-01-01') from dual;
```

Comment: `cast (systimestamp as date)` is quite useless. It is the same as `SYSDATE`, i.e. you do `sysdate+(sysdate - date '1900-01-01')`, i.e. `sysdate+sysdate - date '1900-01-01'`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: In this column some one has stored a timestamp data. - replace systimestamp as date to column_name as date. I know it useless. Just example that works from the box.

Comment: i.e. you do sysdate+(sysdate - date '1900-01-01'), i.e. sysdate+sysdate - date '1900-01-01' - nope go read more about date math in Oracle.

Comment: @Totarae - I will bet a lot of money that Wernfried understands data math in Oracle much better than you ever will. With that out of the way - your computation will find a date that is exactly as many days in the future, measured from today, as 1900-01-01 is in the past. That is, 1900 was about 117 years in the past, your computation will give a date 117 years in the future. What relation does this have to the question asked by the original poster? That is what Wernfried asked.